# Why does my XML parser only returns one string, instead of multiple ones?

Tags: java, xml, loops

I got a problem regarding parsing XML data. I have divided my program into 3 different java files, each containing a class. One of them is rssparser.java. This file holds a function called `iterateRSSFeed(String URL)`, this function returns a string containing the parsed description tag. In my main.java files where my main method is, I call this  `iterateRSSFeed` function this way:

```
rssparser r = new rssparser();
String description = r.iterateRSSFeed();
```

And then I am planning to add this String to a JLabel, this way:

```
JLabel news = new JLabel(description);
```

which obviously works great, my program runs. BUT there are more description tags in my XML file, the JLabel only contains one(1) parsed description tag. I should say that my return statement in the iterateRSSFeed function is "packed" in a for-loop, which in my head should return all of the description tags. But no.

Please ask if something is uncleared or showing of the source code is a better way to provide a solution to my answer. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What do you mean by your return statement is "packed" in a for-loop?  Have you considered returning an array of String or an ArrayList<String>?

Comment: Have you considered the various open source RSS libraries out there? Curn, Rome, etc?

Comment: Just a hint: When you have some time, go back to [your old questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/835585/opous) and look if there are some good answers between them. If yes, accept the best one for each. If no, you might have to edit your question to make it possible to be answered.

Comment: More than a hint: Please accept ***some*** of the answers in your old threads, else you're implying that none of them were useful to you, that the folks who answered them were just wasting their time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Java executes a `return` statement, it will leave the method, and not continue running the loop.

If you want to return multiple values from a method, you have to put them in some object grouping them together. Normally one would use a `List<String>` as return type.

Then your loop will fill the list, and the return statement (after the loop) can return the whole list at once.

If you want to have one large string instead of multiple ones, you'll have to merge them into one.
The easiest would be to simply use the `.toString()` method on the list, this will give (if you are using the default list implementations) something like `[element1, element2, element3]`.

If you don't like the `[,]`, you could simply concatenate them:

```
List<String> list = r.iterateRSSFeed();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : list) {
   b.append(s);
}
String description = b.toString();
```

This will give `element1element2element3`.

As Java's JLabel has some rudimentary HTML support, you could also use this to format your list as a list:

```
List<String> list = r.iterateRSSFeed();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append("<html><ul>");
for(String s : list) {
   b.append("<li>");
   b.append(s);
   b.append("</li>");
}
b.append("</ul>");
String description = b.toString();
```

The result will be `<html><ul><li>element1</li><li>element2</li><li>element3</li></ul>`, which will be formatted by the JLabel as something like this:

- element1
- element2
- element3

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paulo. But how can I add a List<String> to a JPanel? assuming that my function returns a list, and I set a List<String> in my main method to contain this returned list?

Comment: This depends on what you actually want. You can merge the strings in your list to a single string, use a list of panels (which might make sense for an RSS reader), etc.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean JPanel, I meant JLabel. But could you give me a hint how I can merge string in my list to a single string?

Comment: @opus: I added an example to my answer.